# what is the procedure to create Django forms and how to save it in a postgre database?

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to create an application form for my student management system using Django. Can anyone describe the whole procedure, I am confused about using ModelForms or rendering forms simply via HTML. How do we actually create forms and save it and view it in our database? Can the database be viewed only on Django' admin panel or via terminal too?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of possibilities to create a form and manage it.
Look first this Doc page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView

Answer (score 0):

Have you completed the tutorial for Django? It will help you a lot with your questions.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

You can also use this source for creating forms and rendering them in your front-end to supplement the tutorial:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html